# Rendering data on top of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, heat-map

I have an interpolated temperature data samples that covers a map evenly. The data is in the form of (lat,lon,temp). I want to render that data on top of google maps. I tried google heat maps and the rendering is inaccurate.

I assume one way to do it is to have a layer stored in geoserver. I don't want to use this option. I would prefer if the data are included with the webpage and rendered at runtime.

What technique should I follow?

---

It seems that is is possible to render polygons in google maps. You could set the opacity, and color. What I did is interpolating temperature at different degrees, and then creating a large number of polygons that get rendered on top of the map.

The color of each polygon is changed based on the approximated temperature value. I got the following results:

[image: Rendering large number of polygons on top of google maps]

Now I have the following isse: File size is too large, about 1MB is needed to store the code of java script.

How can I send the java script code in compact format to the client?

Also let me know if there is an alternative way to render polygons on top of google maps.

Comment: See http://www.wunderground.com/wundermap/? (Weather Stations) each is individually coloured.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the reply but I want something like this:  http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Annual_Average_Temperature_Map.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Use [Leaflet](http://www.leafletjs.com). It is under 31kb in size and easier to use. You can do a whole lot of things including data rendering in top of google as well as other maps.